# Rails: comparison of BigDecimal with String failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my model I want to compare 2 BigDecimals with each other. In the User table I'm using the column "maxdiscount" (type decimal). This value should then be compared against the value of "discount" (also type decimal). The discount should only should get saved when it's less than or equal to the value that the user typed in.

This is my code snippet:

```
before_save :discount

def discount=(discount)
 if discount.present?
  if current_user.maxdiscount <= discount
    discount = discount.gsub(",", ".")
    self[:discount] = discount
  end
 end
end
```

You might ask: Why gsub? It's because the app will be used by international users (english and german speaking). Both have seperate delimiters so I bring it to the correct format ("." as delimiter).

Whenever I want to save the form I get an error:

> comparison of BigDecimal with String failed

and this line (see code above) gets highlighted:

> if current_user.maxdiscount <= discount

This btw is the form field in my views:

`<%= f.text_field :discount, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Want to grant a Discount?" %>`

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well this sounds clear; `current_user.maxdiscount` is a `BigDecimals` while `discount` is a `String` (created with a *text*_field). You should be able to use `current_user.maxdiscount <= discount.to_d`

Comment: I've tried just now. The error disappeared but the discount does not get saved to the DB. If I remove the whole `if current_user` clause, then it get's saved. So saving to the DB works, but without the check I need. :(

Comment: This is another problem. Have you tried moving the gsub before the comparaison ?

Comment: Found the error... I'm so dumb! Changed the comparison from `<=`to `>=` and it works...